# Trying To Export Activity History Object

Tags: data-export

I'm trying to export and backup the Activity History Object but it's not showing up in the export data option. Any suggestions on how to backup this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity History is a read-only object and is displayed in a related list of closed activities—past events and closed tasks—related to an object. The data you see on the related list on an Account looks into that object.

If you back-up tasks and events you already are backing-up the history, as they have certain fields to indicate if there are closed or completed, then Salesforce automatically lists them as past activities but they remain tasks or events.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: i totally forgot about that thanks for the answer.